# Android GestureListener?

Tags: android, image, gesturedetector

I'm working on application where I have a custom made List View, with image thumbs and some text.I need to be able to show an image in fullscreen mode after I click a ListView item and want to show a custom action bar OnClick image.And I want to be able to swipe between images in fullcreeen mode.The thing that I want to do is something like this : http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/jquery-mobile.html#&ui-state=dialog

Can anyone please show me,help me or give me a suggestions where I can find something like that.I was searching over the internet for something like that but can't find anything. I was thinking of doing this with ImageView's inside ViewFlipper,but as I know I can't swipe images in ViewFlipper.So please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement an OnClickListener on the list view.

[This](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) should give you a very basic idea on how you can implement the photo swipe thingy!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just find that example!

Comment: @Anand S : Can you please see this question regarding gesturelistener? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638512/gesturelistener-not-working-with-androidautolink-email