# GestureListener not working with android:autoLink="email"

Tags: android

This is my Layout xml file.

```
     ...
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/rlt" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor ="#add8e6"
    />  

<TextView 
 android:id="@+id/description"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@+id/tatle_text"
 android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
 android:textColor = "#e3e4fa"
 android:autoLink="email"
 android:textColorLink="#fdd017"
  />
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
```

This is my `onFling()` :

```
   SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener
           = new SimpleOnGestureListener(){
          public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
           float velocityY) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
              final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

              if(xDistance > gs.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > gs.swipe_Max_Distance)
              return false;
               Log.v("Help_developers", "Flinging baby!");
              velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
              velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
                    boolean result = false;

              if(velocityX > gs.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > gs.swipe_Min_Distance){
               if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
               { //Slide to Help_app
                   Intent i=new Intent(Help_developers.this,Help_app.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                finish();
               }
               else
               {
                 //Slide to Help_qanda
                   Intent i=new Intent(Help_developers.this,Help_pending.class);
                   startActivity(i);
               finish();
               }

               result = true;
              }


               return result;
         }
    });
 final GestureDetector gestureDetector
       = new GestureDetector(simpleOnGestureListener);
      rlt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
         {
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d("test", "clicked!");
                    if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))  {
                        Log.d("test", "gesture detected");
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

rlt is the id of RelativeLayout `rlt`.
Now the flinging in the **onFling()** does not work with the **attribute android:autoLink="email"** in the text view with id `description`. But when I remove that attribute, the fling works. I have no idea why this is happening. How can that attribute affect the fling gesture?

**EDIT**
The onTouch() of the `GestureListener` itself is not called. The logs are never recorded in the logcat. When the attribute android:autoLink="email" is present.

**Complete Layout XML File :**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


     <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/rlt" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor ="#ffffff"

        />  

    <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/description"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tatle_text"
     android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
     android:textColor = "#e3e4fa"
     android:autoLink="email"
     android:textColorLink="#fdd017"
     android:
      />
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rlt_touch" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/Home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home"
            android:text="Home"
          />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of turning off the touch handling in the TextView as in my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713176/1023092), we can add a transparent View (as the topmost child of the RelativeLayout) to capture the touch events so that we can selectively forward relevant events to the TextView while still getting all the events to detect the gestures:

- Modify the XML layout, adding the touch-capturing View:

  ```
  ...
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/rlt">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title_text"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="22dp"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:textColor="#add8e6"
          android:background="#ff0000" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/description"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
          android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
          android:textColor="#e3e4fa"
          android:textColorLink="#fdd017"
          android:autoLink="email" />

      <!-- our touch-capturing view -->
      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/rlt_touch" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  ...
  ```
- Modify the Java code, setting our OnTouchListener to the added `rlt_touch` View instead and adding the event forwarding code:

  ```
  final View rt = findViewById(R.id.rlt_touch);
  final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

  rt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      final Rect r = new Rect();
      final Point p1 = new Point();
      final Point p2 = new Point();

      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          Log.d("test", "clicked!");

          if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
              Log.d("test", "gesture detected");
          }

          // offset touch location into the TextView and forward it if relevant
          rt.getGlobalVisibleRect(r, p2);
          tv.getGlobalVisibleRect(r, p1);
          event.offsetLocation(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
          if (r.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
              tv.onTouchEvent(event);
          }

          return true;
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Sorry, still not working. Why does the textview consume the touch events for all parts of the textview. Wouldn't it be enough for it to consume only the events of touching the email part and pass on the rest of the touch events to the GuestureListener.

Comment: It works on my end, not sure why it doesn't works for you. Maybe you can update your answer with the complete layout XML?

Comment: I noticed some issues in the `<TextView>` tag for `+@id/descripion`: (1) there's a stray `android:` line at the end, (2) The  `android:layout_below="@+id/tatle_text"` should probably be `android:layout_below="@id/title_text"`.

Comment: The stray android was a copy mistake. Corrected the @+id/title_text. But still same result. Not even click(touch) is detected.

Comment: Hmm .. did you remember to change the OnTouchListener to be on `rt` instead of `rlt`?

Comment: Strange, it works fine here with that code so unless there's some build issue or something like that, I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Maybe try the `android:background="#0000ff"` trick again to make sure that your code is up to date. Use a different color and maybe add it on the added View to confirm that it is really running.

Comment: I have noticed one more thing, if this can help in anyway. Before you pointed the mistake of android:layout_below="@+id/tatle_text"(in ur earlier comments), the fling was working for the text view @+id/title_text (i.e swiping across the title area resulted in touch and fling). But after correcting that to @+id/title_text, the touch on title_text also stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:autoLink="email"` on your TextView will make it to start consuming touch events, affecting whether your OnTouchListener will get events supplied to it or not.

Here's a couple of changes that you can try so you always get the events:

- Set the `android:linksClickable` attribute on your TextView to false:

  ```
  ...
  android:autoLink="email"
  android:linksClickable="false"
  ...
  ```
- Modify your OnTouchListener to always return true:

  ```
  rlt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          Log.d("test", "clicked!");
          if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
              Log.d("test", "gesture detected");
          }
          return true;
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Tried out your second method. Does not work. Still not even the touches are detected. I did not understand the first method. I just pasted that code. It says setMovemntMethod() is undefined for time relativeLayout.

Comment: My bad, somehow I was under the impression that `rlt` refer to the TextView instead of the RelativeLayout. Let me revise my answer :)

Comment: Answer revised, you need both changes for it to work, I think.

Comment: will links clickabl = false turn off the email link? I need the email link to work.

Comment: made both the changes. Still not even clicks detected.

Comment: Interesting, are you sure your onTouchListener no longer have `return false;` in it anymore? Also, just to confirm that the layout is updated, maybe add a `android:background="#0000ff"` to the TextView xml so you can see it.

Comment: I had put the linkclickable in the wrong textview. It is working. BUT the email is not clickable anymore. The whole point of giving autolink:emil was so that when the user clicks on the email id, he will be directly able to send email to the developers.

Comment: Yeah, if we want to still allow the TextView to process the touch events too, it's probably simpler if we do this differently. I will submit another answer.